# How to sum purchase value from each customer type each month?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

**Customers**

| customer_id | customer_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | student |
| 2 | blue |

**Orders**

| order_id | customer_id | purchase_value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 500 | 2021-06-03 |
| 002 | 2 | 600 | 2021-03-01 |

I want to make a query to show monthly total purchase from each customer type, which is expected to be like this:

| month | student | blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 600 |
| 6 | 500 | 0 |

I've tried to use subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
month(order_date) as month, 
(SELECT sum(order_value)  from orders JOIN customers
    ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
    WHERE customers.customer_type LIKE 'Business'
    GROUP BY month, customers.customer_type) as personal
from orders
JOIN customers
ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
```

But still fail, I want to try to use subquery inside `JOIN` but kinda confuse. Do you have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTH(o.order_date) as month, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.customer_type = 'student' THEN order_value END) as student,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.customer_type = 'blue' THEN order_value END) as blue
FROM orders o JOIN
     customers c
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY MONTH(o.order_date);
```

A subquery is unnecessary.  Note that using `month()` without taking the year to account often produces invalid results.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew how to use `SUM CASE` but now I know.